# Do I need to use an Nginx reverse proxy between AWS Application Load Balancer and Gunicorn running in Fargate?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, docker, django, gunicorn

I have a Django backend application running with Gunicorn inside a Docker container in Fargate.
Since I'm not serving any static files from the Django server (they are being served via Cloudfront) do I need to put an Nginx reverse proxy between the ABL and Gunicorn? Or can I simply send the traffic from the ABL to the Gunicorn container?